# Understanding the SSL Trust Strategy

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

I am trying to understand what [TrustStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustStrategy.html) is to adopt for the method [loadTrustMaterial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#loadTrustMaterial(java.security.KeyStore,%20org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy)).

```
 public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(KeyStore truststore,
                                  TrustStrategy trustStrategy)
                                    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                           KeyStoreException
```

I found four different examples and I am very curious to know the difference between these four as the description is too little to understand the differences/usages/advantages/disadvantages.

Here are the four different code examples:

TrustStrategy: This seems like here we are overriding the standard JSSE certificate verification process but it always returning true so does it trust invalid certificates too?

```
TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        return true;
    }
    };
SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
    .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, trustStrategy);
```

NULL: We are NOT giving any Strategy so what it will do?

```
SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
                            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null);
```

TrustAllStrategy: It will trust all singed certificate so is that secure though?

```
SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
                            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustAllStrategy());
```

TrustSelfSignedStrategy: What is the difference between this and TrustAllStrategy?

```
SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
                            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
```

Help me to understand the difference between these four versions of the example, please? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, trusting all certificates is highly discouraged. Rather add the certificates to the truststore.

The `TrustStategy` is an interface, implemented by some types.

All these methods here are from the apache `httpclient` - the first one (overriding the isTrusted method) is more or less equal to the `TrustAllStrategy` and just creating a custom instance of a `TrustStrategy` where you could define your own way to determine whether a certificate is trusted or not.

See the sourcecode of the [`TrustAllStrategy`](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/ssl/TrustAllStrategy.java) here:

```
public class TrustAllStrategy implements TrustStrategy {

    public static final TrustAllStrategy INSTANCE = new TrustAllStrategy();

    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
        return true;
    }
```

Setting the `TrustStrategy` to null will result in not having any `TrustManager`:

```
   public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
            final KeyStore truststore,
            final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        final TrustManagerFactory tmfactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                trustManagerFactoryAlgorithm == null ? TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
                        : trustManagerFactoryAlgorithm);
        tmfactory.init(truststore);
        final TrustManager[] tms = tmfactory.getTrustManagers();
        if (tms != null) {
            if (trustStrategy != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
                    final TrustManager tm = tms[i];
                    if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                        tms[i] = new TrustManagerDelegate(
                                (X509TrustManager) tm, trustStrategy);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (final TrustManager tm : tms) {
                this.trustManagers.add(tm);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

The [`TrustSelfSignedStrategy`](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/ssl/TrustSelfSignedStrategy.java) works as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean isTrusted(
        final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
    return chain.length == 1;
}
```

A self singed certificate is issued by the target of the certificate. It's generated by default in many applications and often used for intranet purposes.

Comment: When passing null we do have TrustManager since "final TrustManager[] tms" is not an empty array. The question is "is it safer" to pass null in the strategy than passing a "TrustSelfSignedStrategy"? should we use "TrustSelfSignedStrategy" only for testing?

Comment: Sorry for the rather late reply: It really depends on your environment. But since the emerge of Let's Encrypt I am not really certain whether that's a great idea. On the other hand: In a closed and protected hosting environment where a man-in-the-middle attack can be ruled out, there is in my opinion no real need for an externally singed certificate. However, if certain attack vectors cannot be ruled out, I wouldn't rely on self-singed certificates only - and when end users are involved, you'd generally avoid it unless you have your own CA (commonly seen on domain controllers).